# Overriding namespaces in gSOAP

Tags: c++, web-services, gsoap

I am using [`gSOAP`](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net) as a Web Service toolkit and have generated the stub and proxy classes through `soapcpp2` from multiple `WSDL`s all at once. Thus all the namespace bindings are in a single `.nsmap` file.

Now the problem is that all the namespace bindings are being sent with all the method calls I make. The `HTTP POST` packet is unusually large and ugly.

Is there a way to programatically override the namespace bindings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `soapcpp2` and its `-q` flag, it will help you.

Other than that, the `-penv` flag will pack basic gSOAP-related methods within the executable, not including any service objects.

Therefore the files generated with `-penv` can be shared across multiple namespaces, pertaining to different generated gSOAP Web Services.